# Restkit: expected ';' after top level declarator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I am new to iOS development so apologies if my question is uninformed. I am trying to run my simple app in the simulator but the build is failing.  Specifically, it is choking on the first line of the following:

```
FILEMD5HASH_EXTERN CFStringRef FileMD5HashCreateWithPath(CFStringRef filePath; 
                                                     size_t chunkSizeForReadingData);
```

The error tag is as follows :

```
Expected ';' after top level declarator
Unknown type name 'FILEMD5HASH_EXT...'
```

Is there an obvious (or not obvious) fix for this...?

Comment: Please post the code above the lines you already posted.

Answer (score 1):

Dude replace the ";" with ","

the right code is:

```
FILEMD5HASH_EXTERN CFStringRef FileMD5HashCreateWithPath(CFStringRef filePath, 
                                                         size_t chunkSizeForReadingData);
```